# is there any simple method to convert ISO Date to dd/mm/yyyy format in cypher? i tried using "apoc.date.fromISO8601" but its throwing up an error

Tags: datetime, neo4j, cypher, isodate

I'm new to neo4j. I've installed the apoc plugin and changed the **neo4j.conf** file - the method `apoc.date.fromISO8601` shows up when I call `apoc.help("date")` but when I try using it -it throws an error

> "Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureNotFound: There is no procedure with the name `apoc.date.format` registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed."

If this doesn't work is there a simpler way to convert ISO18601 dates to dd/mm/yyyy format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with neo4j 3.1, `apoc.date.fromISO8601` is a *function*, not a *procedure*. This means you can use it like any other function (and not use a`CALL` clause).

For example, this simple query:

```
RETURN apoc.date.fromISO8601('2019-04-03T00:00:00.000Z');
```

returns:

```
╒═══════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"apoc.date.fromISO8601('2019-04-03T00:00:00.000Z')"│
╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│1554249600000                                      │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Similarly, `apoc.date.format` is now a function as well. Here is an example of how to convert an ISO8601 datetime into `dd/mm/yyyy` format:

```
RETURN apoc.date.format(
  apoc.date.fromISO8601('2019-04-03T00:00:00.000Z'),
  "ms",
  "dd/MM/yyyy")
```

which returns:

```
╒══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"apoc.date.format(apoc.date.fromISO8601('2019-04-03T00:00:00.000Z'), "│
│ms", "dd/MM/yyyy")"                                                   │
╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│"03/04/2019"                                                          │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```